# LLVM pass: Error when iterating over Module functions list

Tags: llvm

I am trying in a LLVM pass to iterate over a Module functions list using the list returned by `llvm::Module::getFunctionList()`. I use a loop like this one:

```
    for (auto curFref = M->getFunctionList().begin(), 
              endFref = M->getFunctionList().end(); 
              curFref != endFref; ++curFref) {
        errs() << "found function: " << curFref->getName() << "\n";
    }
```

The first iteration of this loop retrieves a function, as expected, but it does not detect the end of the list and continues just to get in subsequent iterations other objects which are not functions (as reported by their `getName()`), such as that function parameter. After a few iterations it probably reaches some garbage (or NULL) and crash on reference to the current "function" reference.
For example, for this program:

```
int foo(int k) {
    int i, s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        s += i;
    return s;
}
```

Which becomes this IR code:

```
...
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @foo(i32 %k) #0 {
entry:
...
```

The output would look like this:

```
found function: foo
found function: k
found function: #0 0x00007f481f77c46e llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) /home/me/work/llvm-3.8.0/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:322:0
...
```

So you can see that after correctly iterating over `foo` it continued to objects such as the parameter `k`.

I tried this both in a Module pass (in the `runOnModule()`) as well as in a Function pass (using F.getParent() to query the containing Module), and got the same results.

The problem is also replicated on both LLVM 3.8.0 as well as LLVM 3.5.2 .

Any idea what am I missing that I fail to iterate correctly over the returned functions list?

=====

EDIT:

Note that the same behavior is shown when using alternative iteration over the Functions of a Module, such as when using `M.begin()/end()` for the iterator or even when using C++11 range-based `for` loop:`for (Function &curF: M) ...`.

In addition, `M.getFunctionList().size()` cause segmentation fault while it tries to iterate over the list items. So it seems like the functions list is indeed corrupt. But that is the list I get at the very start of `runOnModule()` entry point. So it does not seem like something that was broken by my code.

======

EDIT 2:

I have no idea if this matters, but my LLVM pass is built externally from the LLVM source tree as a dynamically loadable library and then loaded into `opt` using the `-load=foo.so` command line option.

Comment: The answer from @Chandler Carruth solved the problem. In the core of his answer he recommended building LLVM with ninja/cmake, when I built LLVM with make/configure. Rebuilding with ninja/cmake eliminated this problem. While LLVM 3.8.0 release notes suggest that building with make/configure is still supported, this issue suggests that it is broken somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm one of the core LLVM developers.

This is almost certainly a buggy checkout of LLVM, a miscompiled LLVM, or a problem with the fact that your pass is being built as a separate DSO (although I don't see how that could be it).

Numerous parts of LLVM use `M->functions()` (or `M->begin()` & `M->end()`) to iterate only functions. These parts would fail consistently if the behavior was broken. The only difference between these mechanisms and accessing the function list directly as `M->getFunctionList()` does is whether the list is mutable. For the use case you show, they should be *precisely* the same behavior.

I would suggest trying to run the LLVM test suite to make sure it works correctly. If you use the Ninja CMake generator (as I would recommend) to build LLVM:

```
% ninja check-llvm
```

If this fails, especially if it crashes in similar areas, that seems an extremely good indication that the problem is something in your copy of LLVM.

Regardless, SO isn't a great place to get further help here. The answer to the question is "that should in fact work" and I've checked the code in LLVM and I don't see any obvious explanations. So my suggestion would be to try the above, try a fresh copy of LLVM (perhaps top of tree, or the latest release). Make sure you have a sufficiently modern host toolchain for building LLVM. See this section for details:
http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#host-c-toolchain-both-compiler-and-standard-library

If all else fails, try reaching out to the developers on the mailing list:
http://lists.llvm.org/mailman/listinfo/llvm-dev

Or try the IRC channel: http://llvm.org/docs/#irc

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have no doubt that this iterator works for modules built within the LLVM project. But in my case I build my Module pass as shared object and load it using the '-load' option of 'opt'. So I suspect that this use case may have a problem (i.e., everything in LLVM may work while this use case is broken). I also build the pass shared object externally using my own makefile, relying on compilation flags provided by `llvm-config --cppflags`. So it could be that `llvm-config --cppflags` output is different than the flags used for internal build. 
Do you know if these use cases are tested?

Comment: It appears that your recommendation to build with ninja did the "magic". 
My original LLVM build used configure/make. While officially it is still supported in 3.8.0, it seems to have problems. Rebuilding LLVM with ninja and building my Module pass with the same makefile against the updated (ninja) LLVM fixed the problem. 
I guess that make-based build of LLVM is not really supported, even though the release notes suggested that it would stop being supported only from 3.9 . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to use `M->begin()` and `M->end()`instead of `M->getFunctionList().begin()` and `M->getFunctionList().end()`? That works for me.

Comment: `M->begin()/end()` are just a limited version of `M->getFunctionsList().begin()/end()` . Anyway, I tried the simple iterator, too, and got the same unfortunate results.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your input is corrupt somehow? Try running `llvm::verifyModule` on it first (from [Verifier.h](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Verifier_8h.html)) and see what you get - or run `opt -verify` on it, should be the same. Also, you might be interested in the `-verify-each` command-line option for opt.

Comment: The problem is reproduced on any module I test. All my input modules are generated from C code using the command: 

`clang -c -emit-llvm -o foo-preopt.bc foo.c` and then `opt -mem2reg -licm -S -o foo.ll foo-preopt.bc` .

So if any module is corrupt, it is a result of `clang` or the standard `opt` passes. Anyway, `-verify` does not report any problem. I use stable releases of LLVM.

Comment: @ElazarR another idea: make sure you're using the clang that was built along with opt, and not the clang supplied with the operating system.

Comment: I am consistent with the LLVM tools I use. Actually, I avoided installing clang/LLVM packages in my OS. I only use clang/LLVM which I built from the respective releases source code, and I provide explicit path to each tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the following to register your pass :

```
 char SkeletonPass::ID = 0;

// Automatically enable the pass.
// This pass is taken from Adrian Samson Template project http://adriansampson.net/blog/clangpass.html
static void registerSkeletonPass(const PassManagerBuilder &,
                         legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) {
  PM.add(new SkeletonPass());
}
static RegisterStandardPasses
  RegisterMyPass(PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
                 registerSkeletonPass);
```

This works only for FunctionPass/BasicBlockPass, One solution is to use canonical pass as usual without any trick as follows: -

```
char SkeletonPass::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<SkeletonPass> X("passname","Pass Name Analysis");
static void registerPass(const PassManagerBuilder &,
                         legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) {
    PM.add(new SkeletonPass());
}
static RegisterStandardPasses
        RegisterMyPass(PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
                       registerPass);
```

And Run your pass using the following cmd:

```
$ clang -c -O1 -emit-llvm  programs/hello.cpp   -o programs/hello.bc
$ opt   -load build/Debug/libCallgraph.so -passname programs/hello.bc
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not resolve the problem. 
Iterating over M.getFunctionList() still returns items which start with the first function in the module and continue with non-function symbols (objects), such as the parameters of that function (as I report in my question). 
Actually, isa<Function>() reports these objects (function parameters) to be Function objects. So it seems like something is completely wrong in the given iterator.